# What Hibernate version does come bundled in Dropwizard and can it be changed?

Tags: hibernate, java-8, dropwizard, java-time, hibernate-5.x

We have many projects built with Dropwizard, the latest version being used is 1.0.2, we are migrating most of the old code to Java 8, one of the things we want to replace the most is the old Date API and take advantage of the new Java Time API.

So far I haven't found a specification on which version is being bundled with a specific Dropwizard version, we require Hibernate 5 to be able to take advantage of the new Java Time API.

In case the current version we use or the latest version of Dropwizard doesn't come with Hibernate 5, is it possible to replace the bundled version with the most recent Hibernate version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module [*dropwizard-hibernate*, version *1.0.2*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.dropwizard/dropwizard-hibernate/1.0.2), which is [the module to use for Hibernate support](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.2/docs/manual/hibernate.html) has a dependency on [*hibernate-core*, version *5.1.0-FINAL*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.1.0.Final).

So, it has Hibernate 5 "bundled". Or rather, it has Hibernate 5 as a compile time dependency, at least from a Maven point of view. To put it in other words, *Dropwizard 1.0.2* uses Hibernate 5.